# Polars - Select columns not exist with no error

Tags: python, python-polars

Is it possible to select a potentially non-existent column from a polars dataframe without exceptions (return a column with default values or null/None)?

The behavior I really want can be shown in the example as follows:

```
import polars as pl

df1 = pl.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3], "bar": ["sugar", "ham", "spam"]})
df2 = pl.DataFrame({"id": [4, 5, 6], "other": ["a", "b", "b"]})

df1.write_csv("df1.csv")
df2.write_csv("df2.csv")

df = pl.scan_csv("df*.csv").select(["id", "bar"])
res = df.collect()
```

Now, if I run the code above, will get an error since **df2.csv** does not contain column **"bar"**. The result I want is - **res** is just the contents in **df1.csv**, which means the dataframe in **df2.csv** will not be selected due to no column **"bar"** in it.

Comment: Except for changing 'df*.csv' to 'df1.csv`, which I don't think is what you want, this is not supported. You could add the missing columns as nulls on writing the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean as already in the comment mentioned above this functionality doesn't exist in polars, but we can construct a function which would fullfil your needs

```
import glob

def scan_csv_with_columns(file: str, needed_colnames: list[str]) -> pl.LazyFrame:
    file_collector = []
    for filename in glob.glob(file):
        df_scan = pl.scan_csv(filename)
        if (df_scan.columns == needed_colnames):
            file_collector.append(df_scan)
    df = pl.concat(file_collector, how="vertical")
    return(df)

file = "df*.csv"
needed_colnames = ["id", "bar"]
df = scan_csv_with_columns(file, needed_colnames)
df.collect()

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────┐
│ id  ┆ bar   │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ str   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ sugar │
│ 2   ┆ ham   │
│ 3   ┆ spam  │
└─────┴───────┘
```